# Jenkins : Use "Build after other projects are built" and "Build periodically" at the same time

Tags: jenkins, build-triggers

I have two jobs, p1 and p2.

Conditions that trigger p2:

1. p1 build is completed
2. Every Monday

[image]

But I know "Build after other projects are built" and "Build periodically" do not trigger at the same time.
Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes: Make a job p3 than just triggers job p2 when p1 is completed. And schedule p2 to run periodically.

Comment: But when I buid p1, even if p2 is set to "Build periodically", it will still be triggered

Comment: i dont understand, and now i think I might have not understood your question correctly

Comment: I express it differently.

if "p1 build sucess" && "today is Monday"
    trigger "p2"
else
    p2 does nothing

Thank you for your help ><

Comment: ok. You can use conditional step in your job to check on the weekday. Basically you can do the kind of logic you describe in that build step.